# Using ModelAttrbute annotation to submit object from jsp to controller

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, modelattribute

I'm using spring mvc 3.1.0 with jsp/jstl.
To submit object to my controller I'm using the ModelAttribute annotation and all is working fine.
But, when I try to submit a complex object to my controller his value is null.
This is my object model:

UorgVO.java

```
public class UorgVO {

    private String nom;
    private String nomAbrege;
    private UorgVO refUniteOrganisParent;

    //getters&Setters..
}
```

and there is my jsp page:

```
<form:form method="post" action="saveUorg.html"  modelAttribute="uorg" >
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Nom</th>
            <th>Nom abregé</th>
            <th>Unité père</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input  type="text" path="nom" name="nom"/></td>
            <td><input  type="text" path="nomAbrege" name="nomAbrege"/></td>
            <td>
                <select id="refUniteOrganisParent"
                        name="refUniteOrganisParent"
                    path="refUniteOrganisParent">
                    <option  value="null"> --- </option> 
                    <c:forEach items="${listeuos}" var="uorgg" varStatus="status" >
                        <option value="${uorgg}">${uorgg} </option> 
                    </c:forEach>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table> 
    <input type="submit" value="Enregistrer uorg"/> 
</form:form>
```

And my controller is:

```
@RequestMapping(value ="/saveUorg", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView saveUorg(@ModelAttribute("uorg") UorgVO uorg,BindingResult result) {

    System.out.println("My foreign attribute is:" +uorg.getRefUniteOrganisParent());
    return new ModelAndView("uorg_recherche");  
}
```

And the printed value is null, but the other attributes of my object are submitted.

Thank's in advance for help

Comment: Not sure of the answer, but there looks to be a syntactic error in your JSP - on the line `<input type="submit" value="Enregistrer uorg"  <BQ>` you don't close the input tag, and the `<BQ>` tag looks like it shouldn't be there.

Comment: i removed the tag and still not work.

Comment: Using Firebug or similar, can you confirm that your browser is definitely sending the `refUniteOrganisParent=value` parameter when you submit? Also, you won't be able to bind this value directly to a `UorgVO` - because the transmitted value will be a string. You'll need to register a `PropertyEditor` in the controller which will convert the transmitted string to a `UorgVO`. See this [example](https://raymondhlee.wordpress.com/2011/06/08/using-initbinder-in-spring-3-controller/)

Comment: Yes, i used a converter to solve the problem with ConversionServiceFactoryBean Service i'm writing the answer on the post. Thank you Will Keeling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem, i  hope that it gonna help other users who has the same problem. 
By using the service of ConversionServiceFactoryBean.
First, i used the ' form:select ' and 'form:input' , there is my new jsp code :

```
<td><form:input  path="email" type="text"/></td> 
<td>
<form:select path="refUniteOrganisParent.id" items="${listeuos}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="nom"/>
</td>
```

As you can see i retried the id value of the selected item.

Secondly i used this converter:

```
public class UorgConverter implements Converter<Long, UorgVO>{

@Autowired  
private UorgService uo;

@Override
public UorgVO convert(Long id) {

   // actions dealing with the service, to retrieve Uorg object from the id sended by the jsp page

    return uorgItem;        
  }

}
```

After that i configure my xml file by doing this:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven conversion-service="conversionService"/>

<bean id="conversionService" class="my.package.ConversionServiceFactoryBean">
<property name="converters">
    <list>
        <bean class="converter.package.location.UorgConverter"></bean>
        <!--List of my converters -->
    </list>
</property>
</bean>
```

Thank's to everybody who participates in this post to solve the problem.

Mouhie.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the site with form, you should send model. The best way is 
`return new ModelAndView("site","uorg", new UorgVO())` from your controler where `method = GET`.

- [Example](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-3-mvc-handling-forms/)

Comment: That does not answer the question

Comment: @user902691 which site and controller are you talking about ? the page who refers to my form page??

Comment: @mouhie I talk about entry site, where you return `View` name.